# Working with StoryBoards/action

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

When I was trying to set up constraints on my story board I ran into a problem! I added a label to the story board then to code and I tried to run a fading animation to it and .runAction doesn't work. How would I run actions when using storyboards??

Comment: you can use IBAction from the storyboard to create action method for control , but for label you can create IBOutlet and use that outlet to do animations

Comment: can you please explain a bit more? @Pyro

Comment: you can Check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Bgmw9gPOgI

Answer (score 0):

You use control + click-and-drag to drag the outlet over from the storyboard to the code. Make this an IBOutlet and name it blahblahblahLabel. You can then call the fade on blahblahblahLabel. [Here is a video on adding outlets and actions.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-ZaRC8L6uE)

Comment: sorry I didn't get a video link @DanL

Comment: Sorry about that, not sure why the answer came out like that. The link should be available now.

Comment: NO PROBLEM! Thank you! @DanL